# Uninvasive polymorphism

Tags: c++, polymorphism

A simple C++ question : is it possible to call a function or another based on the runtime type of a pointer?

For example I have a class A, and class B is a child of A.

I want to write a function f such that

```
f(A* a)
{//do something
}
f(B* b)
{//do something else
}

//call f()
A* a = new A();
A* b = new B();
f(a);//do something
f(b);//do something, but I'd like it to "do something else"
```

Additional precision : A and B are defined and instanced out of my code, so I can't use regular polymorphism with virtual functions on A and B...

I know you can use some RTTI, but is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: *A and B are defined and instanced out of my code* > do you mean that the variables of type `A` or `B` are instanciated outside your code ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may achieve that using `dynamic_cast`:

```
f(A* a)
{
B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);
if (b == nullptr)
//do something
else
//do something else
}
```

Comment: Actually, when I was talking about RTTI, I thought about calling typeid, a dynamic_cast looks better, even if it's still not as elegant as virtual functions in the classes themselves..

Comment: @Mikarnage pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: not quite though, `dynamic_cast` will work if it is a `C`, derived from `B`, while `typeid` would only indicate pure `B`. Of course, `dynamic_cast` may end up being more costly as a result...

Comment: The OP doesn't say that `A` and `B` are polymorphic classes, and if they aren't `dynamic_cast` won't work here (there won't be any solution in that case).

Comment: @MarkB: he did say: >class B is a child of A

Comment: @Andrey: Yes, but to be polymorphic, `A` must have at least one virtual function.

Answer (score 5):

With those constraints (can't modify the classes), and without using RTTI, no.

You could use a [decorator pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern), wrap `A` and `B` in some other classes and make `f` take those as parameters, but that seems like overkill.

Answer (score 1):

That has nothing to do with polymorphism. `f(A*)` and `f(B*)` aren't the same function, they just happen to have the same identifier. The compiler will pick which one to use. Without RTTI of some sort you can't do this in C++.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are looking for [multimethods](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch). C++ doesn't provide multimethods as a language feature although there is an experimental extension, written by Bjarne Stroustrup. You can use the Visitor pattern as a workaround. A very detailed article on multimethods in C++: [MultiMethods in C++: Finding a complete solution](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7360/MultiMethods-in-C-Finding-a-complete-solution)

Comment: While generally good advise, the fact that the OP may not alter the original `A` and `B` classes pretty much rules out the use of the `Visitor` pattern.